# how to get data from other tables in grid view in yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a module named attendance but value in it is comes from other tables with some conditions. so how can i get id of other tables. my code is like below:

models are:

```
    if($type == 2)
    {
     $model = new Supplier(); 
    }
    elseif($type==3)
    {
     $model = new TruckingCompany();
    }
    elseif($type==4)
    {
     $model = new ServiceProvider();
    }
    elseif($type==5)
    {
     $model = new Landowner();
    }
    elseif($type==6)
    {
     $model = new Refiner();
    }
    elseif($type==8)
    {
     $model = new Worker();
    }
    elseif($type==9)
    {
     $model = new Trainer();
    }
```

now i want to update this record

```
    array(
        'header'=>'Action',         
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{update}',
        'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->id))',
   );
```

now i want to get id of these diffent table for update record and these are different in all tables. i can get it by below line:

```
 'updateButtonUrl'=> 'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->supplier_master_id))';
```

but it is not a proper way to define by these for all tables so what to do in this case... any idea... i am new in yii.

Comment: I'm not sure what is $data, but you can introduce a new method in your models to get an id. And use it like `$data->getId()`.

Comment: but how can i get getId() of different tables?

Comment: if your $data variable represents any of these models, than you can just call this method. It will be applied to the model you are using right now. So, in your model you can return a value of the needed field. It will be some sort of unified interface for all these models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do not you create the URL along with the models like

```
if($type == 2)
    {
     $model = new Supplier(); 
     $updateUrl = 'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->id))';
    }
    elseif($type==3)
    {
     $model = new TruckingCompany();
     $updateUrl = 'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->supplier_master_id))';
    }
```

Pass it to the view while rendering

```
$this->render('view',array('updateUrl'=>$updateUrl));
```

And then finally use it in view file like

```
array(
        'header'=>'Action',         
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{update}',
        'updateButtonUrl'=>$updateUrl,
   );
```

Comment: i  have alredy tried this and it works too. but i want batter way than this. otherwise i will go by this way.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [let me see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256917/980615)'s answer. I would put it in `array` form:

```
$types = array(
    1 => array("modelName"=>"Supplier","url"=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->id))'),
    2 => array("modelName"=>"TruckingCompany","url"=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("attendance/update", array("id"=>$data->supplier_master_id))'),
);
```

Of course you can improve on this by dividing the "url" key for example like this:

```
"url"=>array(
     "route"=>"attendance/update",
     "params"=>'"id"=>$data->id',
 )
```

This way you can pass it like this:

```
if(array_key_exists($type,$types)){ //Checks if you've defined the type.   
    $this->render('view',array(
            'updateUrl'=>$types[$type]['url'],
            'model'=>new $types[$type]['modelName'](), //Creates your object.
         )
    );
    return; //just to be sure.
}
throw new CHTTPException(404, "Type not Found!");
```

Your view would look something like this with the improved "url" key:

```
array(
    'header'=>'Action',         
    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{update}',
    'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl(' . $updateUrl['route'] . ', array(' . $updateUrl['params'] . '))',
);
```

This clears up your code a bit and gets rid of the huge if statement/switch.

The `createUrl string` is still a bit ugly, so you can improve on that further if you would like.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... this is also helpful for me.